# Mocking Toolkit using JMockit Expectations

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

I am trying to mock java.awt.Toolkit.beep() using JMockit Expectations. I have the following code in my test case:

```
new Expectations() {
    Toolkit mock;

    {
        mock.beep();
    }
}.endRecording();
```

When I run the test case (JUnit 4), I get the following exception at the "new Expectations" line:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Code attribute in native or abstract methods in class file $Mock
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that java.awt.Toolkit cannot be mocked because (1) it is abstract, and (2) it is implemented with a "native" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default jmock can only mock interface. To mock class, you need to following [these instructions](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html)